# Proc means breaking output apart using ID and By

Tags: sas

```
proc means data=sashelp.class stackods completetypes;
   ods output summary=classsummary;
   class sex age;
   var height weight;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

For example, if I have this data set, how would I break the output apart by sex and age. Like the first two lines in one box of output.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'breaking output apart'? What do you want as output and why do you think you need to separate the file?

Comment: You should add the NWAY option to your PROC MEAN statement as well, unless you want the totals at various different levels.

Comment: And please mark your previous questions as solved if someone has provided an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to create a grouping variable that indicates the records that share the same formatted values of the CLASS varaibles?

You can either use BY group processing.

```
data want;
   set classsummary;
   by sex age ;
   group + first.age;
run;
```

Or you could use the _CONTROL_ variable instead.

```
data want;
   set classsummary;
   by sex age ;
   retain group 1;
   group + _control_;
run;
```